# What property is used to find the width and height of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that to find width and height of the screen it is screen.height, but what about just the browser window? Thanks.

Comment: window.height ...  window.width??

Comment: in css you can use `vw`:(1% of viewport width) and `vh`:(1% of viewport height)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`

**#Side note #1:** 
You can also use `outerWidth` and `outerHeight`, but this will return the window's toolbars, etc.

**Side note #2:** 
This snippet will show the snippet's width and height because it treats it as the window, not the actual window, but it will work in a true website.

```js
alert("Window Height: "+window.innerHeight);
alert("Window Width: "+window.innerWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var w = window.innerWidth;`

`var h = window.innerHeight;`

Gets the window's height and width: (NOT including toolbars/scrollbars):

The `innerWidth` property returns the inner width of a window's content area.

The `innerHeight` property returns the inner height of a window's content area.

These properties are read-only.

**Note:** Use the `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` properties to get the width/height with toolbars/scrollbars.